# How to find median character of a string in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, median

A median letter in a word is the letter present in the middle of the word and if the word length is even the middle letter is the left one out of the two middle letters.

For example , consider "apple" . The program should return 'p'.

As another example , consider "baba" . The program should return 'a'.

Also , i would like to ask if statistics.median in python would be able to do it .(i don't know if it works on strings as well as I'm new to python programming)

Please prefer to answer in python 2.7 as I'm more comfortable in python 2.7 compared to python 3 , though any help is welcome .

Thanks :D

Comment: using array indexes?

Comment: I'd prefer using a function approach .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python strings are list of characters . For example :

`a = "My String"`

`print a[0] #Prints M`

`print a[-1] #Prints g`

len returns the length of the string in integer

`print len(a) #Prints 9`

using this we can :

```
def returnMedian(mystring):
    return mystring[(len(mystring)-1)/2]  #len returns the length of the string

print returnMedian("abcde")  #prints c
print returnMedian("baba")   #prints a
```

Comment: Use `//2` for python 3 compatibility. (It'll still work in python 2.)

Answer (score 0):

You really should show an attempt to solve the problem yourself. Stack-overflow is not a free code service.

However it will be as simple as getting the size of the array, halving it and then accessing the halved index.

```
my_str = "Hello World!"
half_len = int(len(my_str) / 2)
print my_str[half_len]
```

Make sure to return an `int` (whole number) when halving length of `str`. Otherwise the halved value may return a decimal place value, which will throw an exception when trying to access the `str` by index.

When typecasting a decimal number to `int` (via `int()`), by default it will round down to the nearest whole number. This is common among most (all?) languages.

Comment: Why are you using bash, he is talking about Python?

Comment: Hahaha woops. I've been playing around with too much PHP xD

Comment: That's not bash. Pretty sure it's PHP. And the reason is most likely to not hand the OP the exact code while telling him this isn't a free code service.

Comment: Yeah, let's go with that reason :)

Comment: @ChickenFeet Sir , I tried coding it , but i was looking for a better approach using some in-built function of Python , something that uses python library instead of the normal array appraoch .

Comment: @ChickenFeet ,
Here's my approach 

`import statistics
s = input()
lis = list(s)
med = statistics.median(lis)
print ("%s" %med)`

But , in "apple" it returns l .
Can someone point out the error ? Thanks

Comment: Best to learn the approach of simple tasks like this yourself, rather than relying on libraries. That way you can make sure the code is efficient and avoid miss using libraries.

Comment: I just wanted to learn using libraries in python . Else I was better off at c++ .

Comment: That's fine. As it is we're using functions from the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/), feel free to look around there. Python is a really great language, but for simple specific tasks like this, you won't easily find any dedicated functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
String = "a b a x a d a 5"
Item = String.split(" ")
if float.is_integer(len(Item) / 2):
    Item_1, Item_2 = Item[int((len(Item) / 2) - 1)], Item[int(((len(Item) / 2)))]
    print(Item_1, Item_2)
else:
    Item = Item[int(((len(Item) / 2) - 0.5))]
    print(Item)
```

This is my attempt and it works flawlessly.